# Antivirus software for Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, antivirus

I need free antivirus software with the highest number of features, like

- browser protection
- quick scanning
- deeps canning
- boot time scanning
- removal of bad extensions from the browser

It should not cause much system load. Which free antivirus program is capable of doing these things? If there is no program that meets these specifications, which one comes closest to these specifications?

Comment: @TomJ, No need to delete, but Please read this [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/1576).

Comment: Seems like you want the holy grail of antivirus software: free and capable of anything that the most expensive packages can also do. That is not something we can answer because all antivirus software has good and bad points. Something we CAN answer is something that gets close to your specific requirements, but to be able to answer that we need to know your specific requirements. Please give a (nicely bulleted) list of the specific capabilities that you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Avast for some time: http://www.avast.com/

The free version has anti-virus and anti-malware portection. To fullfill your list, you can get the avast! Browser Cleanup (also free) that will remove unwanted plugins from your browser.

Comment: What makes this piece of software recommendable? What were your experiences with it? What made you decide against it (or are you still using it)? What are its pros and cons? Would be great if you could add some more details (see [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185)). Thanks!

Comment: I can't recommend Avast. It just broke my windows when I uninstalled it (and windows updates was installed). On other pc it haven't detected some yessearch "virus" that came with some usb format tool.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options out there for free antivirus software. What I would recommend is [AVG.](http://free.avg.com)

The free version of AVG can do all of the following:

- Blocks viruses, spyware, & other malware
- Scans web, Twitter, & Facebook links
- Securely deletes files to prevent snooping
- Full System scan
- Quick System scan
- Scheduled Scans
- RootKit Scans

As a piece of free software, it is very capable, and I've yet to see any viruses arise in computers that use it, but that's not to say it is perfect. AVG does offer a paid version for USD $54.99 that has additional features such as:

- Download protection
- File encryption
- Online shopping protection
- Anti-spam

Whether these features are worth the charge is up to you, however the features in the free version are more than capable of protecting you from everyday viruses.

#### [free.avg.com](http://free.avg.com)

Comment: AVG does good work.  Be particular when selecting your download though.  When I rebuilt recently I fell for the tricks and installed the full version (with the additional paid for items) that came with a 30 day trial.  It may have just been me but once the trial wore out I had to uninstall and find the specific download for the free version, couldn't find a way to downgrade.